# MySQL server has gone away in CakePHP bake Console

Tags: mysql, connection

Im currently studying the Cake Bake. Im in this console stuff as per indicated in the book i downloaded from the internet. However I could not advance one more step since im stucked with this error in my console:

```
PHP Warning: mysql_connect(): MySQL server has gone away in C:\wamp\www\cake\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo\dbo_mysql.php on line 543
Warning: mysql_connect(): MySQL server has gone away in C:\wamp\www\cake\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo\dbo_mysql.php on line 543
PHP Warning: mysql_connect(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=2328 in C:\wamp\www\cake\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo\dbo_mysql.php on line 543
```

My GUI works fine since I am loading the home page of Cake PHP in my localhost properly. It even says that I am connected to the database. Does it have something to do with the working path and the app path? This problem's driving me crazy. Thanks for the responses in advanced  :)

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like the connection is being dropped while the shell is running.

I had this happen where a very large CSV was being generated between 2 model functions in a shell script.

Adding the following after the CSV generator fixed the issue.  It ensures there is a connection to the db

```
if (!mysql_ping()) {
    $this->ModelName->getDatasource()->reconnect(); 
}
```